# Python3 pick value from yaml

Tags: python, yaml

I have a yaml file *test.yaml* like below

```
${key_foo}: 'ADjh234hlnlknk'
${key_bar}: 'P98fjljnlkfn'
.
.
.
${key_foobar}: 'knsdlngsg'
```

I am new to python and working on a script. I want to search the key **key_bar** from above file and store its value **P98fjljnlkfn** to a variable without the single quotes. I tried below code but it doesn't print anything. I highly suspect my if statement, but cant figure out what should be the right syntax fir this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import yaml

yaml_file = open("/path/to/file/test.yaml", 'r')
yaml_content = yaml.load(yaml_file)

for key, value in yaml_content.items():
        if (f"{key}") == "key_bar":
                print(f"{value}")
        else:
                continue
```

Can anyone help me get this value?

Comment: you yaml file has invalid structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independent of your YAML structure (I'm no YAML expert), your Python code can change as so:

```py
import yaml

with open("./test.yaml", 'r') as yaml_file:
    yaml_content = yaml.safe_load(yaml_file)

for key, value in yaml_content.items():
    if key == r"${key_bar}":
        print(value)
```

Which returns:

```
P98fjljnlkfn
```